# JavaScript ES6 - Concise way to take only certain keys/parts of a nested JSON array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I've got a JSON array of data that is stored in my app's state. It includes attributes that a detailed page would need (around 10 different fields).

My list view only needs two of those. For example,:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 'Derp',
    "subtitle: 'Derp',
    "another": 'Derp,
    //... more attributes
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    // ... etc
  }
]
```

My list view is only concerned with the id, title, and subtitle. What's the most concise way to obtain the same data, but only with the keys that I specify?

Should I be using map? Or destructuring?

EDIT: Much thanks for the answers despite the effort police showing up. This helped me greatly and I did try for a while to figure out how to do this. I'm coming from Ruby so ES6 is not my forte.

The use case is to only return what a React component needs from a global Redux store that contains all data attributes. For instance, my list view only needs 2/3 attributes from the JSON data. I'm using redux [selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to do this.

2nd/post question: Is there any name for this type of method, where you only take parts of JSON? I want to make a method that does this in a redux selector, and I need to come up with a name. I wanna call it a reducer but that doesn't quite work as the term reducer is already used in the Redux world for methods that modify state.

Comment: Do you have [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or do you have an array of objects?

Comment: @Xotic750 Sorry but I'm not quite sure of the difference. Its a JSON file? Thats the code? Can you tell me?

Comment: @Xotic750 To me it looks like both? I'd like to understand the difference.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) **is always a string** of a serialized object, or a primitive.

Comment: If it's a `.json` file then it's just formatted JSON.  I assume that you are doing this on `nodejs`? Which means that you have no need to parse the file as that get's done for you when you `require` or `import`, you just get an array of objects in your code. Therefore, you access it like @NinaScholz has shown. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Yep! I'm using react native. Cool that explains it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map the values with a deconstructed and reconstructed object.

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.
>
> ```
> var a, b;
> ({a, b} = {a: 10, b: 20});
> console.log(a); // 10
> console.log(b); // 20
> ```

[Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

> ```
> var a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
> var o = {a, b, c};
> ```

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: 'Derp', subtitle: 'Derp', another: 'Derp', bla: 42 }, { id: 2, title: 'Derp', subtitle: 'Derp', another: 'Derp', bla: 42 }],
    short = data.map(({ id, title, subtitle }) => ({ id, title, subtitle }));

console.log(short);
```

Comment: Ahh. I saw a similar stackoverflow post but couldn't put the example together. This makes it more clear!

Comment: Aww, FWIW: reconstruction doesn't work as `({ x.id, x.title, .. })`. (C# has a similar feature with anon types where it would extract the bit after the "." for the field name.. and not how ES6 works.)

Comment: @user2864740, you could use a nested approach for destructuring, like `({ x: { id, title } })`.

Comment: BTW, please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351354/5647260) Meta post. We should not be encouraging people to ask questions where they show little-to-no-effort in solving the problem.

Comment: @AndrewLi I searched around and tried to get this working for over a half hour. I saw a similar answer but the context was missing and I couldn't put it together. I did put in effort, even if you choose to think I didn't. It's honestly kind of lame to sit around and play 'you didn't try' cop.

Comment: @gregblass, i added the right terms of the neede operations.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @NinaScholz!

Comment: @gregblass I guess I was too harsh, honestly sorry. If you would've shown what you gathered by saying 'I saw this answer but it didn't help' it would have been clearer. The fact is this tag is plagued with questions like 'How do I transform this data from A to B' that show absolutely zero effort and expect answers, which yours doesn't do now that I know. In the future, adding some clue as to research that you've done would be best.

Comment: @AndrewLi Hey thanks for responding. It does mean a lot and helps explain things. I will definitely keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ele = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 'Derp',
    "subtitle": 'Derp',
    "another": 'Derp'
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": 'Derp',
    "subtitle": 'Derp',
    "another": 'Derp'
  }
]

console.log(ele.map(({id, title, subtitle}) => 
                    ({id, title, subtitle}) )  )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), then a concise way would be to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and a `reviver`.

```js
const j = '[{"id":1,"title":"Derp","subtitle":"Derp","another":"Derp"},{"id":2,"title":"Derp","subtitle":"Derp","another":"Derp"}]';

const w = ['id', 'title', 'subtitle'];
const o = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => (v && typeof v === 'object' ? v : (w.some(i => i === k) ? v : void 0)));

console.log(o);
```